# storing the date in dbms

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

From the html input field I take in the date as `date/month/year`. Lets say the date entered by the user is 
`28/06/2013`. I want to store this date in my `mysql` dbms.

How do I do this ? I want to store the date for later retrieval.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? Can you post some code of what you have tried so we can see how you want to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For example if the date is `2008/4/5` then we can format it by using below code...

```
        String source="2008/4/5";              
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                       
        java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(format.parse(source).getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any user input directly in SQL. Instead, you should do parametrized queries, and define a `java.sql.Date` parameter. Then, use the `SimpleDateFormat` Java class to turn the user input into a Date object, and fill the parameter with it.